# why for $f(x) =1/(1+1/x)$ the curve pass through the origin

Tags: functions

HI thank's for the future replies.
My question is simple : why for $f(x) =1/(1+1/x)$ the curve pass through the origin so it means $f(0)=0.$
And why $0^{-1}$ is infinite? it's what's telle geogebra application.

Answer (score 1):

For $f(x)$ as you defined it, the value $f(0)$ is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Your function $f$ is not defined for $x \in \{-1,0\}$, because division by $0$ is not defined, so $1+(1+1/0)$ and $1+(1+1(-1))$ are not defined.
But for $x \in \{-1,0\}$ we have $f(x)=x/(1+x)$ in a neighborhood of $0$. Wich means that the graphs of $f$ and $x/(1+x)$ look almost similar and on a picture you may not see a difference. Mathematically this means $\lim_\limits{x \to 0} f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

First question:The function can be written as $f(x) =\frac{x} {x+1}$. So $f(0)=\frac{0}{0+1}=0$

Comment: no, f(0) is not defined

Comment: so two thinkings had appears in this question. if we replace x by 0 we fall on this a first one Thought that leads to conclude that's is impossible in a certain way. but some others they have manipulates the equation. so 1+1/x can be written as (x+1)/x  as our starting function is the inverse, we can write it as x/(x+1) which is defined for 0…

Answer (score -1):

If you write $f(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$ then you should specify that this is written for $x \neq 0$ as orignal function is undefined at $0$ **Or you can say It is out of domain of the function**. We can use limits here as $x$ will never be equal to $0$ but approaching to $0$ in the limit process.
$$f(0)=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$$ $\implies   f(0)\to 0$ as when $x\to 0$ , $\frac{1}{x} \to \infty$ and something over $\infty$ (very large number) is indeed $0$(Actually $\to 0$)